# How do I get/find CoreBluetooth.Framework?

Tags: xcode, xcode5, core-bluetooth

I installed the latest XCode and am trying to add CoreBluetooth.Framework to my project. It isn't in system\library\frameworks. Am I looking in the wrong place or am I missing an install step somewhere?

Answer (score 6):

I hope this helps. Picture is more than 1000 words sometimes.

[image]

Comment: Dhanyavaad! Saved me some time.

Answer (score 2):

In `Xcode` you'll see your project at the top of the left hand pane, click on it. Once you've clicked on it click on `General` then find `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`. Click the `+` button, search for `CoreBluetooth` once you find it click on it and click `Add`.

For a visual representation check out Apple's instructions [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html)

Answer (score 0):

In case you need this for Bluetooth Explorer, you have to symlink the framework first, it is hidden in IOBluetooth.framework:

```
sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/IOBluetooth.framework/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework
```